# php scripts activating by themselves

Tags: php, session

All right so I've been looking all over the net and I can't seem to find any solution for my problem. My apologies if this has been asked in the past.

I'm sure there's a very simple answer for this: A while back I built a website for a client. This website has an administration system in which some pages are locked using a $_SESSION variable called 'level', which basically checks whether the user is an administrator or not. Furthermore, some pages are locked with the usual log in session variables, to ensure that only logged in people can access these pages.

Now the problem is that on two of my pages, the php scripts seems to run completely by themselves. The first page is just a page that resends all of the activation emails to every user in the DB. This page can only be accessed by being logged in, and being an administrator. The second page can only be accessed by going through PayPal. The PayPal script has fallback support which checks whether there are PayPal post variables.

Anyone know why these scripts are running by themselves? It gets bothersome when random emails are continually sent to customers or administrators. I probably did something wrong somewhere. I thought it might just be the Google crawler activating the scripts, but wouldn't the crawler have to be logged in to access the scripts?

Comment: Are you able to access the web server log files and see who, if anyone, is calling those script pages?

Comment: could possibly be [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: It would be nice to see some code, otherwise it'll be extremely difficult to see if there's something wrong somewhere...

Comment: You can verify if there is set any cronjob and you can paste some code here to see if there might by any other programming problem.

Comment: You'd be surprised what Google can do: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Comment: Maybe you or your client accidentally included the scripts somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of things.

One approach could be that search engines are executing your scripts.

A couple of years ago I was hired to look into what could be causing the deletion of all pages made with their homemade CMS.

Looking through their access logs revealed that two search engines was trying to index the content in the administration frontend. Including all the *Delete page* links.

The reason why this could occur was a combination of two things.

The first was the administrators browser plugins from the two search engines. Documentation proved that pages a client visited was sent to the search engines from their plugin.

Secondly, when the search engine attempted to index a session protected page, the original developer of their CMS forgot to put an `exit;` after the `header('Location: ...');`part which meant that the rest of the code on the page still got executed.

**The solution**

I fixed the problem by adding `exit;` to the code:

```
If( ! isset($_SESSION['level']) )
{
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit; // stops further execution of code
}
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: Ah! I was missing my exit, you were right. Whether this will solve the problem, I'm not too sure, will have to wait and see. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

Check the access logs of your server and see when and what is calling those pages (if they are being called).

If something is accessing those pages (spider, person, etc) that shouldn't be, you have a security issue.

I highly doubt the scripts are 'calling themselves'

Comment: I also don't see the scripts calling themselves, would be rather odd. Logs seem clean though. I tried Repox's solution, all I have to do now is wait and see whether this actually fixed the problem, but it seems rather probable.

Answer (score 0):

To find why they are being called, after you check if the session variable is set, and you find it isn't, add

```
file_put_contents('./log/log.txt', print_r($_SERVER));
```

Create yourself a directory "log" and a writabel file "log.txt" and the source should appear in there.

The other useful function is debug_backtrace(). Bit trickier to use this, but:

```
if ($handle = @fopen('./log/log.txt', 'a')) {
    for ($i=1; $i<count($aBack); $i++) {
        if (isset($aBack[$i]['file'])) {
            fwrite($handle, $aBack[$i]['file'] . '/' . $aBack[$i]['line'] . "\n\r";
        } else {
            fwrite($handle, 'Anonymous function' . "\n\r";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Should give you a log of what oath was used. (Code typed verbatim - sorry for typos, but you should be able to work out from there)

Note that most client information (IP, referer etc) is forgable, but the calling URI isn't. It'll give you lots of info about what's calling them.